# ASPNET MVC : Getting rid of apple-touch-icon errors : The controller for path Controller1/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to get rid of these errors but still they keep showing up in my logs.

I have this article http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons about touch icons and did as advised :

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="./apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="./apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="76x76" href="./apple-touch-icon-76x76-precomposed.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="./apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="120x120" href="./apple-touch-icon-120x120-precomposed.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="./apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="152x152" href="./apple-touch-icon-152x152-precomposed.png"/>
```

I have set the files at the root of my website.

With this done I no longer see the error for  the main controller BUT see errors for every other controllers that are on my website.

Any help is welcome to get rid of these errors once for all

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using relative paths.
The browser resolves those paths relative to the directory in the current URL, which is typically your controller name.

You want to use absolute paths, by removing the `.`.

Answer (score 1):

The "./apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png" is a relative path, which may differ depending on the context.

Two options would be to either use absolute paths, such as:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="152x152" href="/Images/apple-touch-icon-152x152-precomposed.png"/>
```

Or, if you are using the Razor engine, you can use a helper:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="@Url.Content("~/Images/apple-touch-icon-152x152-precomposed.png")" />
```